# How to pass previous React route through query param to next route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, query-string

How to store previous `location` (route) in a constant and pass it through a query param?

I am using React router v5.

In my React (route) component I have a Link

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Link to={{ pathname: MyPage, search: `?redirectUrl=previous-route` }}>
 Go to page
</Link>
```

I need to pass the previous location route to the next route (`MyPage`) through the query param `redirectUrl`.

```
<Link to={{ pathname: MyPage, search: `?redirectUrl=${<----- My previous route value here}` }}>
  Go to page
</Link>
```

How do I manage that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `useLocation` hook to get the current location to pass along as the previous location for the next page.

```
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { pathname } = useLocation();

...

<Link to={{ pathname: MyPage, search: `?redirectUrl=${pathname}` }}>
 Go to page
</Link>
```

Comment: with `const { pathname } = useLocation();` you get the path of current route. I need to store the  _previous_ route in a const (similar you get from `state: { from: pathname }` and pass that through my query param?

Comment: @meez You want the route path before the route you are navigating from? You could use the above on *that* previous route and forward via this link. Are you sure you want the *previous* previous route path? What is the use case?